# How to get pagination for JSON data working in PHP?

Tags: php, json, pagination

With the webservice I'm making, users are able to send URL parameters with 'start' and 'limit'.
That way, they can choose how many JSON objects are shown per page and at what page they want to start.

This is the PHP code I've made for this

```
$start = (int)$_GET['start'];
        $limit = (int)$_GET['limit'];

        switch ($start) {
            case 1:
                $previous = 1;
                break;
            default:
                $previous = $start - 1;
        }

        $next = $start + 1;

        $file = file_get_contents("data.json");
        $data = json_decode($file);

        $total_items = count($data->items);
        $total_pages = round($total_items / $limit);

        $first = 1;

        $data->pagination = array(
            'currentPage' => $start,
            'currentItems' => $limit,
            'totalPages' => $total_pages,
            'totalItems' => $total_items,
            'links' => [
                array(
                    "rel" => "first",
                    "page" => $first,
                    "href" => "http://somelink/restful/?start=$first&limit=$limit"
                ),
                array(
                    "rel" => "last",
                    "page" => $total_pages,
                    "href" => "http://somelink/0879644/restful/?start=$total_pages&limit=$limit"
                ),
                array(
                    "rel" => "previous",
                    "page" => $previous,
                    "href" => "http://somelink/0879644/restful/?start=$previous&limit=$limit"
                ),
                array(
                    "rel" => "next",
                    "page" => $next,
                    "href" => "http://somelink/0879644/restful/?start=$next&limit=$limit"
                )
            ]
        );

        file_put_contents('data.json', json_encode($data));
```

Pagination counts work perfectly with this.

My question is: how do I get the pagination to work properly, so with a limited amount of data per page and multiple pages with data?

**EDIT**

This is a fragment of the JSON data

```
    {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Lorem",
          "artist": "Ipsum",
          "genre": "Pop",
          "week": "4",
          "highest_rating": "3",
          "year": "2014",
          "youtube": "www.youtube.com",
          "links": [
            {
              "rel": "self",
              "href": "somelink/0879644/restful/music/1"
            },
            {
              "rel": "collection",
              "href": "somelink/0879644/restful/music"
            }
          ]
        }
 ]
    }
  ],
"pagination": {
    "currentPage": 1,
    "currentItems": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalItems": 8,
    "links": [
      {
        "rel": "first",
        "page": 1,
        "href": "somelink/0879644/restful/"
      },
      {
        "rel": "last",
        "page": 1,
        "href": "somelink/0879644/restful/"
      },
      {
        "rel": "previous",
        "page": 1,
        "href": "somelink/0879644/restful/"
      },
      {
        "rel": "next",
        "page": 2,
        "href": "somelink/0879644/restful/"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but ou should use $total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit); instead of round() to get the correct total number of pages.

Comment: Makes total sense now. Didn't work as well as I thought it did. immediately fixed a little issue I had. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$start = (int)$_GET['start'];
$limit = (int)$_GET['limit'];

switch ($start) {
    case 1:
        $previous = 1;
        break;
    default:
        $previous = $start - 1;
}

$next = $start + 1;

$file = file_get_contents("data.json");
$data = json_decode($file);

$total_items = count($data->items);
$total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit);

$data->items = array_slice($data->items, ($start-1)*$limit, $limit);

$first = 1;

$data->pagination = array(
    'currentPage' => $start,
    'currentItems' => $limit,
    'totalPages' => $total_pages,
    'totalItems' => $total_items,
    'links' => [
        array(
            "rel" => "first",
            "page" => $first,
            "href" => "http://somelink/restful/?start=$first&limit=$limit"
        ),
        array(
            "rel" => "last",
            "page" => $total_pages,
            "href" => "http://somelink/0879644/restful/?start=$total_pages&limit=$limit"
        ),
        array(
            "rel" => "previous",
            "page" => $previous,
            "href" => "http://somelink/0879644/restful/?start=$previous&limit=$limit"
        ),
        array(
            "rel" => "next",
            "page" => $next,
            "href" => "http://somelink/0879644/restful/?start=$next&limit=$limit"
        )
    ]
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

Test it in your browser. It paginates over given simplified json

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Getting this warning: array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given.

Comment: Paste fragment of data.json

Comment: Well, kinda hard to explain because it's something I have to do for school so there are all sorts of requirements to it. But this is the way it should be (At least, that was what I was told)

Comment: I've fixed array_slice line

Comment: @user3182261 `json_decode` returns an object by default, pass `true` as the second arg. [reference](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: I think there something wrong with requirements. If you overwrite data source at the end then on next request you will have less data

Comment: Well, I only posted part of the PHP code because it would be too much otherwise. But overwriting the data isn't giving me any problems. It's just the parting of the JSON data and making multiple pages.

Comment: You're the man! Exactly how I wanted it. Thank you so much. You've been of great help!

Comment: I know this is old, but why are you making totalPages, previous etc and I'm i not seeing it in my browser?